Confusing Non-recursive Dirichlet Inverse Formula for Arithmetic Functions
Recall: Definition of Dirichlet Convolution and Arithmetic Functions
An arithmetic function $f$ is a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,4, \cdots\}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of complex numbers.
Given two arithmetic functions $f$ and $g$, define the Dirichlet convolution as:
$$(f * g)(n) := \sum_{d|n} f(d)g\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$$
Dirichlet Inverse
For all positive integers $n$, define the arithmetic function $\varepsilon$ as:
$$
\begin{equation}
  \varepsilon (n) = 
  \begin{cases}
    1, & n = 1 \\
    0, & n > 1
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
Everyone can check that for all arithmetic functions $f$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $(f * \varepsilon)(n) = (\varepsilon * f)(n) = f(n)$.
A Dirichlet inverse is an arithmetic function $f^{-1}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$(f^{-1} * f)(n) = \varepsilon (n) = (f * f^{-1})(n)$$
According to this article, a Dirichlet inverse exists iff $f(1) \neq 0$.
Problem
I found this article that talks about how to find a non-recursive way to find the Dirichlet inverse of an arithmetic function.
I know the recursive formula, which is
$$
\begin{equation}
  f^{-1}(n) = 
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{f(1)} & \text{if } n=1\\
    \frac{-1}{f(1)}\sum_{\substack{d|n \\ d<n}} f^{-1}(d) f(\frac{n}{d}) & \text{if } n > 1
  \end{cases}
\end{equation} \label{rec} \tag{$*$}
$$
The problem is that I cannot comprehend well the following non-recursive formula for the Dirichlet inverse formula (this is the equation $(2.4)$ at page $120$ from article):
Let $f$ be an arithmetic fucntion with $f(1) = 1$ and let $n$ be arbitrary but fixed positive intger with $n \geq 2$. Let $e_1, e_2, e_3, \cdots, e_m$ be the divisors of $n$ that are bigger than $1$. Then,
$$f^{-1}(n) = \sum_{\substack {l_1, l_2, \cdots , l_m \geq 0} \\ e_{1}^{l_1} e_{2}^{l_2} \cdots 
 e_{m}^{l_m} = n} (-1)^{\sum_{i=i}^{m} l_i} \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} l_i \right)!}{\prod_{i=1}^{m} (l_i!)} \prod_{i=1}^{m} f(e_i)^{l_i} \label{non-rec} \tag{$**$}$$
I tried to do an example with $f(n) = n^2$ (in particular $n=4$), and what I've got was that with the equation in $\eqref{rec}$ I got $0$, but I don't know how to do this with the equation in $\eqref{non-rec}$. More especifically, I dont know what the first sum means (the one with $e_1, e_2, \cdots$ as indeces).
Attempt
Here is my logic:
First, I calculted the $e_i$'s and $l_i$'s. Notice that $(e_1, l_1) = (2, 2)$ and $(e_2, l_2) = (4, 0)$. It satisfies $e_1^{l_1} e_2^{l_2} = 4$. So, $m=2$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(4) = (-1)^2 \frac{(2)!}{(1!)} f(2)^2 + (-1)^{2+0} \frac{(2+0)!}{(1!)(2!)} f(2)^2 f(4)^0 = 2f(2)^2 + f(2)^2 = 48$. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Pls help!
PS: I know there is an easier way to calculate $f^{-1}$ when $f$ is completely multiplicative or generally, a multiplicative function. I just want to understand the summation notation. Any hints are welcomed. I also found this post that explains the general way of an non-iterative formula much like $\eqref{non-rec}$, but I understand more the formula from the article.
Thank you in advance!
References
HAUKANNEN, P. (2000). Expressions for the Dirichlet of an Arithmetical Function. NNTDM 6 (2000), 118-124, 118–124. https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-06/NNTDM-06-4-118-124.pdf


First, I calculted the $e_i$'s and $l_i$'s. Notice that $(e_1, l_1) = (2, 2)$ and $(e_2, l_2) = (4, 0)$. It satisfies $e_1^{l_1} e_2^{l_2} = 4$. So, $m=2$.

This is not correct; the values of the $\ell_i$ are not fixed. We have $e_1 = 2, e_2 = 4$ so we want to know what pairs $(\ell_1, \ell_2)$ satisfy $2^{\ell_1} 4^{\ell_2} = 4$ (and the sum is over all of these). You've given one solution, namely $(2, 0)$, and there's a second solution, namely $(0, 1)$.
You also made a few mistakes interpreting what the terms of the summation are supposed to be; note that your result does not end up involving $f(4)$ so it can't be right. There are two terms corresponding to the two pairs above and they are
$$f^{-1}(4) = (-1)^{2+0} \frac{2!}{2! 0!} f(2)^2 + (-1)^{0+1} \frac{1!}{0!1!} f(4) = \boxed{ f(2)^2 - f(4) }$$
which for $f(n) = n^2$ gives $0$.

Excellent explanation! Thank you so much!
